# What is open toolchain

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

what is open tool chain in iphone applications development, i want to learn it from scratch .
is there any link that can help me to learn.
Thanx

Answer (score 1):

It means developing using tools independent from the iPhone SDK. It mainly has the set of opensource compilation tools (gcc, etc.) and API headers constructed by reverse engineering.

Non-Mac OS X environment, e.g. Windows and iPhoneOS need the open toolchain to target iPhone as the SDK is Mac-only. Legally, the SDK license prohibit development for iPhone projects *not* for AppStore, so the open toolchain must be used for apps on jailbroken platforms.

You can find detailed info in http://www.saurik.com/id/4.

(If you're targeting AppStore, you can forget this term.)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [iPhone Open Application Development, 2nd Edition By: Jonathan Zdziarski.](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780596155346)

It's the best overall resource I've found on Open Tool and it's a decent if somewhat dated introduction to iPhone programming in general.

However, I would caution you that the market for open tool software is very small. I think the only people who really use it for anything significant beyond amusement are enterprise developers who want to highly customize their company's iPhone use. If your thinking about basing a mass market business on Open Tool I would do some research on how profitable that is likely to be before jumping in.

Answer (score 0):

it LITERALLY means that you gonna have things like compiling (and other dev tools) directly in your iPhone and NOT external, so Unix (BSD/Darwin) own programs inside iPhone and not xCode on outside (your computer)